# How would you use adobe typekit?

Tags: typekit

Simple steps to use adobe typekit account fonts?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for how to use adobe typekit fonts and found the below:

http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6780-adding-fonts-to-your-site